# Displacement breaks model

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface, displacement, solidify-modifier

I am having issues with displacement blowing up my model. Here is the file link https://pasteall.org/blend/3a30add0510d4884829a7afcb4d08c62

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have to specify a texture for the *Displacement* modifier. Your model has flipped normals (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/216140/107598) You need to correct them else you get shading issues (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/118555/107598). What is the purpose of the *Solidify* modifier? Just asking because with the level 4 *Subdivision Surface* modifier this will generate a lot of extra vertices.

Comment: @Blunder Thank you so much! Solidify is there because I am making the model thicker for resin printing purposes! Ill give the face changes a try when I get home. Thank you again, this is my first time using blender and im just trying to clean up a 3D model of my MMO character to print.